# Update class variables using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Is there a way/what is the best way to use multiprocessing to do this:

I have a class which at initialization will run a function to set one of its class variables. This function takes quite long. I would like that the class initially has this value set to i.e. None. The function should run in the background not holding up the program and when finished set the class variable to its correct value.

What I tried which didn't work is just starting a process of that function inside the class init:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

class example:

  def __init__(self):
    self.var = None
    p = mp.Process(target=self.takes_long)
    p.start()

  def takes_long(self):
    time.sleep(5)
    self.var = ['a', 'b', 'c']

if __name__ == '__main__':
  e = example()
  while True:
    print(e.var)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Here I would hope that after 5 seconds the variable would change to `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

This doesn't work. It stays at None. How can I let the process change the value of the class properly?

Comment: Can you use a thread instead?

Comment: Yes probably that would be the right attempt. I tried it with this test function and it does what I want there.